# Can I use aab to reduce the size of Android packages with Mac OS / XF?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I read about using aab for reducing the size of Android packages. Is that something that can be done on a Mac with VS and Xamarin Forms latest releases Dec 2019

Comment: Yes check this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/

Comment: @RendyDelRosario that does not answer the question, which was asking if a similar function existed for Mac OS. The link only talks about Android.